# KVM or Xen for VGA Pass-through

Tags: virtualization, xen

I'm in the planning phase of setting up a personal virtualization server. One of the virtual machines I want to setup is a Windows box with Steam. Ideally, I want to stream higher-end games to my laptop and a future Steam Link using Steam's In-House Streaming.

I know I need to setup VGA Pass through so that I can give my Windows box full access to a dedicated graphics card. I'm a beginner to virtualization at this level, and from what I can tell there are two choices that will work for what I'm trying to do: KVM or Xen.

For the setup I'm going for, which would be better in terms of ease of setup, performance, and documentation?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is definitely not "about managing information technology systems in a business environment"... so it does not belong here.

Comment: Use QEMU (with KVM), it's easier to configure and there is already lots of info out there about VGA passthrough.